# WPF Equivalent of Winforms ListControl.Format Event? (Formatting List items with a delegate)

Tags: wpf

I'm finally making the switch from Winforms to WPF  (3.5) , and I am trying to move this functionality over:

A common practice of mine is to control formatting of a list/combo box display in the Format event, by passing a delegate to the control's container.  In the Format Event, the delegate formats the display text of the list item as I want it to appear (e.g. by combining properties of the displaying item).
Is there any equivalent way with the WPF Combo/List box to specify a delegate for formatting the appearance of List Item text at run time?
Thanks,
YS

FYI - Here  what I was trying to get at, as described in my answer:

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private List<Foo> l = new List<Foo>();
    //Formatting done by delegate, passed to converter.
    MyConverter<Foo>  cv = new MyConverter<Foo>(f=> "#" + f.ID + " = " + f.Name);
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Resources.Add("myConverter", cv);
        l.Add(new Foo(){ID=1, Name = "aaaa aaaa"});
        l.Add(new Foo(){ID=2, Name = "bbbb bbbb "});
        DataContext = l;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}


public class Foo
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


}


public class MyConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{
    private Func< T, string> _formatter { get; set; }
    public MyConverter(Func<T, string> Formatter)
    {
        _formatter = Formatter;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return _formatter((T)value);
    }

}
```

And then in the xaml:

`<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=myConverter}}"> </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone breathlessly following this question...
I posted the question on the MS WPF forum, and from the answer there I think the best path for me is to create a custom IValueConverter where I can pass in a delegate to use in the Convert method, and set that as the Converter in the DataTemplate.

Comment: I seriously hope this is a joke - why is everything so much more difficult in WPF!?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to format each item the same, look into ListBox.ItemContainerStyle. This will contain the template for each item. If you are looking into changing the styles for each item based on some logic, use the above along with ListBox.ItemContainerStyleSelector. See msdn doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyleselector.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want to do. I want to format with delegate logic, not styles.